# Show friends who use same app, without requiring friends list permission

Tags: facebook, permissions, privacy

It would be nice if my Facebook app's users could see who among their friends use the same app.

Documented methods to do this require the "Friends List" permission, which sounds creepy.

Is there any way that does NOT require this permission?

I don't even need to see the list server-side, if it could be processed/displayed entirely client-side it would be perfect.

Note: My app is not a game.

Comment: Just to make sure we've got this straight: You want to be able to access the Facebook Friends list, without requesting permission to access the Friends list?

Comment: yes what u do with users friend who uses a app coz u dont want users friend ... its tricky

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but not exactly how you describe it. You won't be able to simply display a list "as is" to your user, but you will be able to show them which of their friends also use your application indirectly.

When you initiate a requests dialog within your application, you can pass a `filter` parameter to the dialog that will only display certain users in the multi-friend selector.

Here is an extract from the description of the `filter` parameter from the [Requests Dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

> **filter**
>   This controls what set of friends someone sees if a multi-friend
>   selector is shown. Default is an empty string, which shows a
>   multi-friend selector that shows all friends, with filters for friends
>   using the same app, and friends not using it. If `all`, `app_users` and
>   `app_non_users` is specified, the sender will only be able to see
>   friends in that list and will not be able to filter to another list.

So as this passage (quite vaguely) describes, passing a value of `app_users` as the filter to the dialog will only display the user's friends that also have this application installed.

It's mostly used for in-application requests between users where one user can send gifts or perform actions on/for other users within the application.

Comment: +1 Great! It seems that it only works for games though: `Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps.`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - ahhh... that sucks :/ I think it's pretty obvious that many applications simply define themselves as "games" even though they aren't really games. Not sure if you can actually change that setting on an application once it is created though...